# Vertical scrolling on Child element of ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager2 which has 10 pages. ViewPager2 has a vertical orientation. while each page inside the ViewPager2 has horizontally scrollable content. My problem is that the pages (child of ViewPager2) are not horizontally scrollable.

Please suggest a solution.

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ticker" />                                                      =======<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Without some XMLs it's hard, you should provide some code we can see and use.

Comment: Question updated. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Should you add ```android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"``` to ViewPager2's children?

Comment: @anhtuannd NO. I have not added this line.